# laravel query builder or inside where

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have the following query and i want to know if this is possible in laravel's querybuilder:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (column = value OR column = value2) AND column2 LIKE '%value3%'
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
DB::table('table')
  ->where(function($q) use ($value, $value2) {
      $q->where('column', $value)
        ->orWhere('column', $value2);
  })
  ->where('column2', 'like', '%'.%value3.'%')
  ->get();
```

If you have multiple values, you can put them into a simple array and use `whereIn()`:

```
DB::table('table')
  ->whereIn('column', $valuesArray)
  ->where('column2', 'like', '%'.%value3.'%')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use closure in where for ex.

```
\DB::table('table_name')
 ->where(function($q){
       $q->where('column', 'value1')
         ->orWhere('column', 'value2');
  })
  ->where('column2', 'LIKE', '%value3%');
```

check here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping

Answer (score 0):

You can do this according to make desired query

```
       DB::table('table_name')
      ->where('column', 'value1')
      ->orWhere('column', 'value2')
      ->where('column2', 'like', '%value3%');
```

Comment: that will not generate the grouped expression, instead it will add or condition in query without parenthesis